# Unable to increase Linux VM storage using VBox and Gparted

Tags: linux, virtualbox, partitioning, gparted, rhel-7

I have a running VM of storage around 20GB which was assigned initially during creation.. I followed the VBox documentation on how to add more storage using the VBoxManage command ( which was successful )..

I also understand that after adding more storage to the disk I need to allocate this space using the Gparted utility which I did..

My problem now is that after doing so I still see the extra storage as unallocated under Linux using command lsblk

```
[root@mq01 ~]# lsblk
NAME          MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda             8:0    0   30G  0 disk
├─sda1          8:1    0    1G  0 part /boot
└─sda2          8:2    0 28.3G  0 part
  ├─rhel-root 253:0    0 17.5G  0 lvm  /
  └─rhel-swap 253:1    0    2G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
sr0            11:0    1  317M  0 rom
```

and the storage does not seem to be added when I check using df -h command

```
[root@mq01 ~]# df -h
Filesystem             Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/rhel-root   18G   18G   20K 100% /
devtmpfs               905M     0  905M   0% /dev
tmpfs                  920M  8.0K  920M   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                  920M  8.7M  912M   1% /run
tmpfs                  920M     0  920M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1             1014M  179M  836M  18% /boot
tmpfs                  184M     0  184M   0% /run/user/0
```

and from the Gparted utility the space seems to have been allocated

[image]

What exactly am I missing? I appreciate your help folks.. Thanks

Comment: I think it is /  - or let me know how to check. Thanks @KamilMaciorowski

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was missing a few steps.. I needed to extend the logical volume using

```
lvextend -L +8G /dev/mapper/rhel-root
```

and then grow the FS using

```
xfs_growfs /dev/mapper/rhel-root
```

Now everything looks good..

```
[root@mq01 ~]# df -h
Filesystem             Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/rhel-root   26G   15G   11G  58% /
devtmpfs               905M     0  905M   0% /dev
tmpfs                  920M  8.0K  920M   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                  920M  8.7M  912M   1% /run
tmpfs                  920M     0  920M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1             1014M  179M  836M  18% /boot
tmpfs                  184M     0  184M   0% /run/user/0
```

Thanks